# Как установить старую версию node.js и модулей?

Tags: node.js

Нужно установить на сервер версию node.js и различные модули датированные 2014-ым годом. Нашёл на Github'e все необходимые версии, но как их правильно поставить?

Comment: `npm install modulename@version`

Comment: + для установки нужной версии ноды nvm (https://github.com/creationix/nvm) или n (https://github.com/tj/n)

Answer (score 1):

Для управления версиями Node.js очень удобно пользоваться [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) (для винды есть чуть менее функциональный аналог).  Можете установить сразу несколько версий Node.js и переключаться между ними по желанию:

`nvm use 4.4.7
Now using node v4.4.7`

Для того чтобы установить определенную версию модулей просто укажите нужные версии в файле [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies). Если вы устанавливаете модули указывая параметр --save, то эти модули прописываются в package.json, там можно узакать нужную версию модуля, а затем выполнить **npm update**

```
npm install modulename --save
```

package.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "modulename1": "0.11.2",
    "modulename2": "^1.4.1"
  }
}
```